# .htaccess fake directory and username

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently I have this code in .htaccess file to create a fake directory

e.g.

```
http://www.mysite.com/something.php
```

will then become

```
http://www.mysite.com/something
```

I am using the following code for that

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./$1.php
```

but what I want to do now is allow users to have a url like

```
http://www.mysite.com/myusername
```

that url will then point to this page

```
http://www.mysite.com/profile.php?username=myusername
```

I just wanted to know if this was possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: This obviously isn't going to work - the first rule will rewrite everything to .php! It will never even get to the username rewrite rule.